# R dplyr historic maxima

Tags: r, dplyr

I have used in this example to create a maximum temperature for each season. In addition, I am now trying to include an additional column that shows, for each row, the historic maximum temperature in the winter of that specific year (e.g. the value of winter 2001 for the seasons in 2001, winter 2002 for 2002 seasons, etc.).

I could solve this by subsetting and merging outside `dplyr`, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this elegantly within `dplyr`?

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(DataCombine)

df = expand.grid(year = 2000:2003,
                 season = c("spring","summer","fall","winter"),
                 month=1:3)

df$temp = rpois(dim(df)[1], 5) #  temperature

df2 = df %>%
  group_by(year, season) %>%
  summarise(max_temp=max(temp))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try

```
 library(dplyr)  
 df %>%
      group_by(year) %>%
      mutate(max_temp = max(temp[season=='winter']))
```

Or an option using `left_join`

```
  left_join(df,
        df %>% 
          filter(season=='winter') %>%
          group_by(year) %>%
           summarise(max_temp=max(temp)))
```

A compact option with `data.table` would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, max_temp := max(temp[season=='winter']) ,year][]
```

Comment: @AlexA.  Thanks, initially I was using `mutate`, but later changed to `summarise`, I think the code is more compact now

Comment: Nice work. This is the kind of elegant solution I would expect from `dplyr`. :)